# How to know the class type without using instanceOf or getClass()?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

I have a class Person which is inherited by Student and Employee.
I have another class PersonList, it has a list of type Person i.e List (elements can be of both Student and Employee type)

There is a 3rd party API which has two overloaded methods i.e

`void display(Employee emp)` and `void display (Student student)`

When I iterate over Person list, I need to know the object type so that I can call to the appropriate display() method.

I dont want to use instanceOf or getClass().

Comment: Why do you have these restrictions?

Comment: the problem is that in this iteration you MUST know the special implementation for using one of both methods. A better solution is an interface that you implement for every implementation `public interface PersonInterface {public void display(); }`

Comment: I was asked this question in an interview today. I could not think of the third way since I am home for 2 hours. :)

Comment: I cant change anything in the third party API

Comment: Can you change the `Employee`, `Person` and `Student` classes?

Comment: I dont think so, the interviewer kept on insisting that come up with something else may be use some sort of polymorphism technique to know. I was clueless.

Comment: Yes we can change the three class i.e Employee, Person and Student

Comment: You don't have to do anything, the appropriate method will be called automatically....

Comment: @assylias he must know the special implementation because there are both students and employee in the list. Both are persons but a student is not a employee and vice versa. And the third part lib has only the methods with student and employee. Or have i some missunderstanding?

Comment: @assylias: Not here, the scenario is backwards. You're passing a general type through more specific methods which is a conversion you can't do.

Comment: Oooooh - I missed that bit sorry. @pL4Gu33 you were right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, the third-party API in this case is badly designed. Especially if you are allowed to change the classes it relies on...

But anyway, if you are allowed to change the classes, you can add a method like `displayMe` (I'm assuming your third party class is called `PersonPrinter`).

```
abstract class Person {
    abstract public void displayMe();
}

class Employee extends Person {
    public void displayMe() {
        PersonPrinter.display(this);
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    public void displayMe() {
        PersonPrinter.display(this);
    }
}
```

Since each of the classes knows what it is, it will pick the correct version of `display` from `PersonPrinter`.

Now you can write your loop like this:

```
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add(new Employee());
    personList.add(new Student());
    for ( Person p : personList ) {
        p.displayMe();
    }
```